# Hibernate - why use many-to-one to represent a one-to-one?

Tags: hibernate, orm

I've seen people use many-to-one mappings to represent one-to-one relationships. I've also read this in a book  by Gavin King and on articles.

For example, if a customer can have exactly one shipping address, and a shipping address can belong to only one customer, the mapping is given as:

```
<class name="Customer" table="CUSTOMERS">
    ...
    <many-to-one name="shippingAddress"
                 class="Address"
                 column="SHIPPING_ADDRESS_ID"
                 cascade="save-update"
                 unique="true"/>
    ...
</class>
```

The book reasons as (quoting it):

> "You don't care what's on the target side of the association, so you can treat it like a *to-one* association without the *many* part."

My question is, why use `many-to-one` and not `one-to-one`? What is it about a `one-to-one` that makes it a less desirable option to `many-to-one`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There are several ways to implement a one-to-one association in a database: you can share a primary key but you can also use a foreign key relationship with a unique constraint (one table has a foreign key column that references the primary key of the associated table).

In the later case, the hibernate way to map this is to use a `many-to-one` association (that allows to specify the foreign key).

> The reason is simple: You don’t care
>   what’s on the target side of the
>   association, so you can treat it like
>   a to-one association without the many
>   part. *All you want is to express “This
>   entity has a property that is a
>   reference to an instance of another
>   entity” and use a foreign key field to
>   represent that relationship.*

In other words, using a `many-to-one` is the way to map **one-to-one foreign key associations** (which are actually maybe more frequent than **shared primary key one-to-one associations**).

Comment: Can you offer an example to clarify your point about mapping the "foreign key relationship with a unique constraint"? Since such a relationship is logically one-to-one, why would you map it as many-to-one in hibernate?

Comment: This seems to answer _when_ but not _why_...?

Comment: The downside though, is that you cannot use `inverse="true"`. It doesn't work on `many-to-one`.

Comment: hi do you know how to do cascade delete this way?

Answer (score 7):

The biggest difference is, with a shared-key **one-to-one mapping** the 2 objects are bound to each other, they exists together.

f.e. if you create a **Person** and an **Address** class that are bound to tables with same name, each person will have exactly one address...

- class Person -> properties: address
- table Person -> columns: id, name
- table Address -> columns: id, city

With **many-to one** relationship the table structure changes a bit, but the same effect can be achieved...

- class Person -> properties: address
- table Person -> columns: id, name,
  addressid (fk)
- table Address -> columns: id,
  city

...but even more. Now this person can have multiple addresses:

- class Person -> properties: address
- table Person -> columns: id, name,
  addressid (fk), shippingaddressid (fk)
- table Address -> columns: id,
  city

The two foreign keys (addressid and shippingaddressid) could point to a single DB entry...or a single address could belong to 2-3 persons. so whats a many-to-one from the person's side it's a one-to-many from the address side.

and just guess what does a one-to-many association with only 1 item look like? Yeah, just like a one-to-one...

NOTE: address actually should be a **value object**, should not be shared in DB (so it's a silly example, but i guess it'll be o.k.)

**So in short:**

1. in OR mapping one-to-one is harder to handle
2. one to one has it's limitations
3. using many to one instead is more flexible and same thing can be achieved with

Answer (score 3):

I would say the problem is fundamentally related to the object-relational impedance mismatch. To be able to relate the two object representations in a database, you need to have some sort of relationship between their tables. However, the database knows only the 1:N relationship: all the others are derived from it.

With relational databases and object languages, it's up to the developer to find the least unnatural representation of the concept he/she wants to represent (in this case, a 1:1 relationship).

Answer (score 0):

It's even in official Hibernate docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-bidirectional-121.

It's not totally unreasonable. The **many-to-one** end says: I am mapped via one of my columns to an ID of the -one end. You would use the exact same database schema for many-to-one.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it hibernate requires that the primary key of both objects match in a 1 to 1 relationship. Many to 1 avoids that requirement.

However many to 1 loses the information that there should only be one or perhaps no object on the many side.