# Mapping over several Tables

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, hibernate-mapping

i have 3 tables:

```
    TABLE BOOKING (
  BOOK_ID  
  PERSONAL_ID                             
  ORGINIZER                      
  TITLE
    PRIMARY KEY ( BOOK_ID )
    FOREIGN KEY ( PERSONAL_ID)
);

TABLE ROOM
(
  ID
  BOOK_ID
  FROM                  
  UNTIL                        
  QUANTITY                   
  PRIMARY KEY ( ID) 
  FOREIGN KEY ( BOOK_ID)
);

TABLE PERSONAL
    (
      ID
      PERSONAL_ID
      NAME
      SURNAME
      EMAIL         
      PRIMARY KEY ( ID) 
    );
```

I map over the table ROOM like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">

<class name="Depp.Domain.Booking, Depp.Core" >
    <id name="ID" unsaved-value="0" column="ID">
        <generator class="native">
            <!--<param name="sequence">GLOBALSEQUENCE</param>-->
        </generator>
    </id>
    <property name="Title" ></property>
    <property name="TitleEnabled" type="yes_no">
        <column name="THEMA_ENABLED"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ORGANIZER" column="PERSONAL_ID" not-null="true" ></property>
    <bag name="ROOM" inverse="true" lazy="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan" >
        <key column="BOOK_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="Depp.Domain.ROOM, Depp.Core"/>
    </bag>

</class>
```

My Question is how can i map over the Table `PERSONAL`? My Problem is that `PERSONAL`doesn't have a FOREIGN KEY so i don't know how to map over `PERSONAL`. I need to get the `NAME`, `SURNAME` and `EMAIL` from that table.

Hope someone can help me

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The association between Booking and Personal can be map as a [unidirectional many-to-one association](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html#assoc-intro).

Use [property-ref](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) attribute to specified the field other than the personal primary key to join with, in your case it`s the personalId attribute that correspond to the database column PERSONAL_ID instead of the ID of the Personal class.

> **[property-ref](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-manytoone) (optional)**
>
> the name of a property of the associated
> class that is joined to this foreign key. If not specified, the
> primary key of the associated class is used.

See this stackoverflow question on [Hibernate - why use many-to-one to represent a one-to-one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452987/hibernate-why-use-many-to-one-to-represent-a-one-to-one)

Mapping

```
<class name="Booking" >
    <id name="ID" unsaved-value="0" column="ID">
        <generator class="native">
            <!--<param name="sequence">GLOBALSEQUENCE</param>-->
        </generator>
    </id>
    ...
    <many-to-one name="personal" column="PERSONAL_ID"   property-ref="personalId" not-null="true"/>
    ...
</class>

<class name="Personal">
    <id name="id" column="ID">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    
    <property name="personalId" column="personal_id" />
    <property name="name" />
    <property name="surname" />
    <property name="email" />
    
</class>
```

Java

```
public class Booking{

    private Long id;

    private Personal personal;
    ...
}



public class Personal 
{
    Long id;
        
    private Long personalId;   
    private String name;        
    private String surname;
    private String email;
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me. I tried it but every time i set up the many to one relationship or the class Personal my website crashes. dont know why.

Comment: Use property-ref, because you don't want to join on the primary key ID of the personal table but on the PERSONAL_ID column. I modify the answer.

Answer (score 0):

how about using HQL to get list of that table objects ? TO get mapped objects, there must be FKs defined isn't it, otherwise how hibernate will be able to map columns ?

Comment: BOOKING is the main Table. I can map over ROOM because ROOM has a FK "BOOK_ID". But i cant map over PERSONAL because that Table has no FK "BOOK_ID". But the BOOKING table has a FK "PERSONAL_ID". Is it possible to get the Name, Surname and Email from table PERSONAL, with the "PERSONAL_ID" form the BOOKING table?

Comment: but the personal_id is present in both tables, you can use any value isnt it ?

Comment: seems I am not answering the right question :c what exactly you want to do ? I mean, with the returned result ? Because you can get list of all persons by a separate HQL query as I answered.

Comment: i want to display the returned values i a table. Do you mean with seperate HQL query a new File with which i can map over PERSONAL?

Comment: yes, something like that. because i dont see a need of including booking table when you want to show personal list. Otherwise how about trying two way relationship in mapping ?

Comment: look. There are Persons who do bookings. I need the names of them. I dont need the whole Personal list. I need only that Person which had a done a booking. Thats why there is a PERSONAL_ID in the Booking table. But i dont know how to get the name of that Person from the PERSONAL table. So i have to get the name from that Person with the PERSONAL_ID from the BOOKING table

Comment: if there is mapping, hibernate will give you person object within booking object.