# Database and Hibernate one-to-one best appraoch

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

Which is general and better approach to implement one-to-one relation and mapping with DB and Hibernate from bellow
Assume that we have Customer & Contact tables.
1) Can keep contact_id in Customer table as foreign key
2) Can keep customer_id in Contact table as foreign key
How to implement hibernate mapping for both?

I have implemented customer and contact tables using 2nd option
When i'm tryiing to do hibernatetemplate.save(customer);

i'm getting bellow Exception:
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`contact_info`, CONSTRAINT `contact_info_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`CUSTOMER_ID`) REFERENCES `customers` (`ID`))

Present mapping is

```
@Entity
CustomerEntity {
    .....
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private ContactInfoEntity contactDetails;
    .....
}
@Entity
ContactInfoEntity {

    @Column(name="CUSTOMER_ID")
    private int customerId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@onetoone` is always difficult and confusing to implement. You can use `@ManyToOne` and set the property to `unique=true`. It is mentioned in the Hibernate documentation that `@manytoone` can be used over `@onetoone` as it is clean that way.

Some one posted a similar question here:

[Hibernate - why use many-to-one to represent a one-to-one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452987/hibernate-why-use-many-to-one-to-represent-a-one-to-one)