# Foreign Key Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, db2

I have a problem with Hibernate, I want to create a table that is related to another table, but when I generate it, the foreign key is wrong.

Is it possible that Hibernate has a bug?

Here is the code that I use to generate the Foreign Key:

```
@Id
@JsonProperty("account")
@OneToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "ACCOUNTCODE_K",
        referencedColumnName = "CODE_K"/*, insertable = false, updatable = false*/),
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "INVOICEDEBTOR_K",
        referencedColumnName = "INVOICEDEBTOR_K"/*, insertable = false, updatable = false*/)
})
@javax.validation.constraints.NotNull(message="El campo no puede ser nulo")
private Account account;
```

And here is the DDL generated in the database:

```
ALTER TABLE "INVOICES"."ACCOUNTBIEN_T" 
ADD CONSTRAINT "FKSWGAGEC55PBL7KIHFE19FWBLO" FOREIGN KEY
    ("ACCOUNTCODE_K",
     "INVOICEDEBTOR_K")
REFERENCES "INVOICES"."ACCOUNT_T"
    ("INVOICEDEBTOR_K",
     "CODE_K")
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION
ENFORCED
ENABLE QUERY OPTIMIZATION ;
```

You can see that ACCOUNTCODE_K reference INVOICEDEBTOR_K when It would be reference CODE_K and INVOICEDEBTOR_K to the other INVOICEDEBTOR_K.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you checked the database by yourself? I think that's just the message, order maybe not correct, but the reference key should be right. Expect your checking result.

Comment: Yes, I checked the database and the foreing key is wrong.

Comment: Jose: One thing, this should be @ManyToOne right?Or it is really a OneToOne?

Comment: Also, which version of Hibernate/JPA are you using?

Comment: We need that the relation be OneToOne, we use the hibernate´s version 5.2.17.Final

Comment: Can you just to try `ManyToOne` to see if it works? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2452987/hibernate-why-use-many-to-one-to-represent-a-one-to-one